# addView pushes text below drawerlayout

Tags: android

I am totally new to the android app development, and I have a problem:

I am adding content to my main LinearLayout when pressing a button on my DrawerLayout:

```
private void switchTo(String text) {
    final LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.0F);
    final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setLayoutParams(params);
    textView.setText("New text: " + text);
    content.addView(textView, 0);
}
```

But this adds the text on top of my LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:gravity="bottom">

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#e6e6e6"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/navList"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:background="#cccccc"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

How can I manage to add the text after the DrawerLayout, because adding the text right now pushes the DrawerLayout down (If it is unclear, I would like the DrawerLayout to stay on top of the page in height, while rendering text "next to it")

Comment: You can just create an emtpy `LinearLayout` below `DrawerLayout` and add view(s) to that `LinearLayout` instead.

Comment: If you really want it vertically below the `DrawerLayout`, just remove the second argument in `content.addView(textView, 0);`. That is, drop the `, 0`. This seems like an odd setup, though.

Comment: @Joshua I already tried that, but adding content to that empty LinearLayout does not show up :(

Comment: @MikeM. when I remove the ,0, no text shows up anymore, why is that so?

Comment: Oh, yeah, whoops. You'll also need to set the `DrawerLayout`'s `layout_height` to `0dp`, and its `layout_weight` to `1`.

Comment: @MikeM. Hey thanks! That works! But i guess i didn't express myself that well, I would like the text to start on top of the page, but to slide the DrawerLayout over the text, how can I achieve that??

Comment: OK, that makes a lot more sense. You want to put your `LinearLayout` inside the `DrawerLayout`, above the `ListView`. The first child `View` in a `DrawerLayout` is its content `View`; the stuff the drawer opens over. You can change the `DrawerLayout`'s attributes back to what you had originally, then.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you so much, it works now!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DrawerLayout works like this

> To add a navigation drawer, declare your user interface with a
>   DrawerLayout object as the root view of your layout. Inside the
>   DrawerLayout, **add one view** that contains the main content for the
>   screen (your primary layout when the drawer is hidden) **and another**
>   **view** that contains the contents of the navigation drawer.

[Check this information regarding DrawerLayouts](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

Your layout file should have 2 views :
**1 - Main content (when then drawer is closed)

2 - The drawer itself**

I would have your layout like this then

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The main content view : here you define the layout of your activity -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <!-- The main content view : here you define the layout of your activity -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"> 

        <!-- The navigation drawer -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/navList"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left|start"
            android:background="#cccccc"/>

    <LinearLayout/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Additionally, when you specify :

```
 content.addView(textView, 0);
```

**You are strictly saying that you want to add your textView to the first position of your content.**
This adds your textView before every other causing the textView to be before the drawerLayout
[Check this reference regarding ViewGroups and adding views](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html)

So, the modified code would be

```
..
private LinearLayout contentFrame;
..
contentFrame = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
...

private void switchTo(String text) {
    final LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.0F);
    final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setLayoutParams(params);
    textView.setText("New text: " + text);
    contentFrame.addView(textView);
}
```